# jqPlot bar chart with linear scale

Tags: jquery, charts, jqplot, bar-chart

I would like to get bar chart with linear ticks on xaxis, here the code -

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
       var years =  ['2000', '2010', '2030']
       var chartData =  [8140221, 8402213, 8544930]    
       $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
                     var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart0', [chartData], {
                        title: 'Some Plot',
                         seriesDefaults:{
                             renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                             rendererOptions: {
                                barPadding: 1,
                                barMargin: 15,
                                barDirection: 'vertical',
                                barWidth: 50
                            }, 
                            pointLabels: { show: true }
                        },
                        axes: {
                            xaxis: {                            
                                    renderer:  $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                                    ticks: axisDates
                            },
                            yaxis: {
                                tickOptions: {
                                    formatString: '%d'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        highlighter: {
                            sizeAdjust: 7.5
                        },
                        cursor: {
                            show: true
                        }
                    });

            });</script>
```

[image]

Here, on xaxis we got 2000, 2010, and 2030 still the distance is shown as same. Is there anyway I can show more distance between 2010 and 2030 so that it gives rough idea that difference of second interval is bigger than first one. I tried providing tickInterval and numberTicks but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Do I need to use different renderer or configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have found a solution to this issue- however, there is one way to "hack" the graph to illustrate the differences in the three bars.

If your data set is within an "expected" range, you can use the `min` and `max` attributes to limit the range and by doing so you can show the true difference between the values.

An example of how to do this is provided [here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html).